# Wildcard as part of path in a AWS CloudFront invalidation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

The current documentation describes that the wildcard can only appear at the end of the invalidation path. How do I then invalidate a certain file if I do not know the path? In the console, it is possible to invalidate "/*/test.jpg" but after the process is complete, CloudFront still sends the old image.

Comment: It this a one time operation where you could afford to just invalidate everything? `/*`

Comment: I have over 5 million images in the bucket and do not want to delete them all at once from the cache.

Comment: makes sense for sure. unfortunately, as you indicated the wildcard must appear at the end of the path. i don't think there's a way to selectively invalidate for this use case unless you have a way to query a datasource and create an array of those paths you'd want to invalidate.